# Design a header script to run after the document is finished loading

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a javascript function, "loadFramework()" that modifies an HTML document. Specifically, it repeatedly runs the jQuery command `$("#element-id").load("document/name.html")`, which injects the HTML in document/name.html directly into the element with #element-id.

Originally, I ran loadFramework() in a script in the document's header. However, since then I've realized that the function fails if the page has not loaded yet, since it relies on there being an element with #element-id.

I can't figure out how to get this function to run when it should. A simple solution seemed to be setting it to be the document.onload function:

```
document.onload = function() {
    loadFramework();
}
```

But in this case it never seems to run at all.

How do I make sure a header function runs only after the document has loaded?

Comment: Funny, if I google "JQuery only run when document loads" the first result is the [reference manual](https://api.jquery.com/ready/) for perhaps the most common function in all of jQuery, which does just what you want...

Comment: try `console.log("this code runs")` as your first line of code in the `loadFramework()` method. This helps you check if this method gets executed at all.

Comment: The simplest (and also most obvious) solution is to put your script right before the `</body>` tag. It's also considered [a best practice](https://developer.yahoo.com/performance/rules.html) to do so.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use `window.onload` if you are looking for a vanilla JS option

`window.onload = function() {
  loadFramework();
}`

Answer (score 0):

Jquery load takes additional argument "complete". You can run the javascript there. So the code would be:

```
$("#element-id").load("document/name.html", function(){
    loadFramework();
});
```

You can also use $(document).ready(function{loadFramework()}) inside the html you are loading.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to execute the `loadFramework()` method after "document/name.html" is loaded, I would suggest the following code.

```
$(function() {
    $("#element-id").load("document/name.html", function(){
        loadFramework();
    });
});
```